# Does OWASP Java Encoder Project escape all XSS?

Tags: java, security, xss, owasp

Does OWASP Java Encoder Project escape all XSS?
by methods

```
Encode.forHtmlContent(value)
Encode.forJavaScript(value)
Encode.forXml(value)
```

or better to use other solutions?

What OWASP solution you are advise for Java app?

Comment: also take a look at http://canyouxssthis.com/ for a list of html sanitizers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ESAPI is no longer a flagship project for OWASP.](http://off-the-wall-security.blogspot.com/2014/03/esapi-no-longer-owasp-flagship-project.html)  There has been no releases since 2013, which means the project is stale.

If all you need is output escaping, [use the encoder project.](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-java-encoder/)  That one is maintained.

No single solution can be guaranteed to sanitize all XSS.  You have to allow that a clever attacker might be able to exploit a bug in the HTML sanitizer.

Comment: As an FYI, in 2016 I helped resurrect the project and it is now being maintained again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think if you are looking for encoding API to stop XSS then OWASP Java Encoder is best option. For context based encoding to stooping XSS, I would prefer java encoder over ESAPI